# How to extract common elements from list of lists of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to build dictionaries (one contains all common elements and the other one contains the different elements) out of a list of dictionaries.

Now I've managed to get it working for a list of 2 dictionaries by converting to a set of tuples and then getting the unique keys as well as the differences with the intersection and difference methods but I don't know how to go about a list of varying length (sometimes I'll have 3 or 4 dictionaries in my list).

I'm sure I need to use map or reduce/lambda function but I can't figure it out.

This is my input:

```
all_maps = [
    [{'key': 'target', 'value': 'true'},
     {'key': 'region_name', 'value': 'europe'},
     {'field': 'AccessToken', 'key': 'token','path': 'test/path'}],
    [{'key': 'target', 'value': 'true'},
     {'key': 'region_name', 'value': 'usa'},
     {'field': 'AccessToken', 'key': 'token', 'path': 'test/path'}],
    [{'key': 'target', 'value': 'true'},
     {'key': 'region_name', 'value': 'japan'},
     {'field': 'AccessToken', 'key': 'token', 'path': 'test/path'}]
]
```

What I want is to get 4 dictionaries as such:

```
intersection = {'key': 'target', 'value': 'true'},
               {'field': 'AccessToken', 'key': 'token', 'path': 'test/path'}
```

```
diff1 = {'key': 'region_name', 'value': 'europe'}
diff2 = {'key': 'region_name', 'value': 'usa'}
diff3 = {'key': 'region_name', 'value': 'japan'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple answer would be to flatten the `all_maps` list and separate each items based on its `list.count()` value:

```py
def flatten(map_groups):
    items = []
    for group in map_groups:
        items.extend(group)
    return items


def intersection(map_groups):
    unique = []
    items = flatten(map_groups)
    for item in items:
        if item not in unique and items.count(item) > 1:
            unique.append(item)
    return unique


def difference(map_groups):
    unique = []
    items = flatten(map_groups)
    for item in items:
        if item not in unique and items.count(item) == 1:
            unique.append(item)
    return unique
```

Here's the output using these functions:

```py
>>> intersection(all_maps)
[{'key': 'target', 'value': 'true'},
 {'field': 'AccessToken', 'key': 'token', 'path': 'test/path'}]

>>> difference(all_maps)
[{'key': 'region_name', 'value': 'europe'},
 {'key': 'region_name', 'value': 'usa'},
 {'key': 'region_name', 'value': 'japan'}]
```

For a more advanced implementation, you can look into `set()`.

Comment: Pretty sweet. It's a lot simpler than my set/tuple/dict solution.